# Light box that is compatible with Views?

Tags: views, 7, javascript

I've created a content type, let's call it Person. 
I've got a View which generates a grid of thumbnail images, one for each Person.
When the user clicks on one of these thumbnails, I'd like to open that Person node in a lightbox (without all of the header and footer decorations, just the content of the node).

What lightbox modules are compatible with Views? I tried ColorBox, but I'm not seeing a colorbox option in the "Link Image to.." which is where I would expect to see it.

Is colorbox compatible with Views and I'm just looking in the wrong place?

If it's not, what modules are compatible with Views to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Lightbox 2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) module integrates with Views.  I use it on my site.  This module is extremely popular (more than 100,000 installs).

Unfortunately, [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/799216) describes why Views and Colorbox are currently not compatible.

Comment: Does it support enclosing a node in the lightbox? I added this module to my site and then went to my Views configuration and tried to change the "Link Image to..." dropdown on my image Field, but I didn't see any reference to Lightbox. Am I looking in the wrong spot?

Comment: Change the Formatter on the settings for the image field, not "Link Image to..."

Comment: Ah, ok, I see the choice now. However, it only gives me the ability to link one image type to a different image type (for example, thumbnail -> original). However, I want to open the entire node in the lightbox. Does this module do this?

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head how to configure it to open the whole node.  If the node is a gallery of pictures, however, you can use the built-in gallery feature of lightbox to display all the images together.

Comment: I want to display the whole node (not just images). I'll keep looking around to see if I can find some info on how to display a whole node in a lightbox. Thanks for your continued help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is way to achieve what you want. Adding a lightbox to an image is as simple as adding 'lightbox' to the link's rel attribute. Since you want to display content in the lightbox then you should go and rewrite your image and select "Output this field as a link". Construct the correct path for the link and add the rel attribute. Take a look at [this](http://drupal.org/node/144488) for more info and examples.

Answer (score 1):

You need to output the image field as a link (there's a checkbox on the setting of this field on Views) and set the `rel` attribute to `lightmodal` according to [this page](http://drupal.org/node/144488). And you need to write a very small custom module as shown in [this comment](http://drupal.org/node/276378#comment-4741860) which outputs your node's content **without** all the other bits (html, body tags, sidebars etc).

Otherwise you can use `lightframe` in the `rel` attribute and just put the link of the node there, which should display the whole page in a lightbox with the sidebars, menus, headers & footers etc.